# jQuery in a HTML formatted string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some AJAX call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: <some url>,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(html){
        // do some jQuery on the response html
        // like this: $('#someDIV').text();
    }
});
```

The response `html` likes this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- header things -->
</head>
    <div id="someDIV">
        content
    <div>
</html>
```

Can I do the query on that response html without append the code to current page?

Comment: If I undestood correctly your question, you can normally do `var newHtml = $(html);` and manipulate the variable without appending it to the body.

Comment: Please be aware that `$(html)` will *flatten* the DOM and remove elements like HEAD and BODY and any SCRIPT tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply [wrap by jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#htmlString) and do the rest.

```
var $html = $(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

Query the response string to find the div element inside it like below

```js
var response = '<html> <head></head> <div id="someDIV"> content <div> </html>'
console.log($(response).find("div"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = $(dynamichtml);
```

Later, you can query it.

```
var item = content.select({jqueryCriteria});
```